# "failed to evaluate expression" when fiddling with INSERT INTO on DataBricks SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks

I receive the following error when I try to insert into a casted date in my table

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: failed to evaluate expression to_date('01.01.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'): Cannot evaluate expression: to_date(01.01.2016, Some(dd.mm.yyyy)); line 2 pos 1

```
insert into E_Par_Holidays
values  
     ('BE', to_date('01.01.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
```

The table is defined as:

```
create  table E_Par_Holidays (
    Country varchar(255),
    Holiday date
    );
```

And oddly the following SQL statement works like a charm:

```
SELECT to_date('01.01.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as DateExample;
```

Thank you for your help!

I fixed it by using insert into select logic

```
insert into E_Par_Holidays
SELECT 'BE', to_date('01.01.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't use insert statement in spark sql.

instead use dataframe writer api

```
dataframe.write.mode(SaveMode.append).jdbc(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:   insert into  alfiya.timestamptbl values(cast('0001-01-01 17:00:00.000 +0300' as timestamp ));